# How to add "getAttributeText" to "related view" section?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, error, phtml, related-products

I am getting the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on a non-object in /catalog/product/list/related.phtml on line 21` while add "getAttributeText" in the file `/catalog/product/list/related.phtml`.

This is code:

```
<?php
$merchant_name = $_product->getAttributeText('merchant_name');
if ($merchant_name){
   echo "By ". $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('merchant_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
 elseif ($_product->getIsEbayaffiliate()){
        echo "By eBay";
}
 else {
        echo "By Home Done";
}
?>
```

FYI, I am using the same "getAttributeText" in the following files and it's working perfectly:

```
 1. catalog/product/view.phtml
 2. catalog/product/list.phtml
 3. catalog/product/new.phtml
 4. catalog/product/special.phtml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it as simple as changing the variable `$_product` to `$_item`?

The error message you see is telling you that `$_product` is not an object.

Typically in `related.phtml` we write

```
foreach($this->getItems() as $_item)
{
    $_item->getName();
}
```

But I note you may also need to ensure that the attribute `merchant_name` has been included in the related items collection.

[no longer relevant and or misleading]
<del>I prepared a longer in-depth answer but it is not rigorous and so I will report more tomorrow.</del>

<del>As a test if you echo out `get_class($_item)` because I can't remember if `$_item` in `related.phtml` is `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`. If $_item isn't `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` then try `$_item->getProduct()` but I haven't tried it.</del>

Comment: Yeah... That's fixed... "simple as changing the variable $_product to $_item"